# Transformation which makes diagonal matrix elements into sign of its values?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I am curious whether there is a transformation $U$ such that $UAU^{-1} = \operatorname{sign}(A)$ where $A$ is a diagonal matrix.
For instance, let $A$ be given in the following form.
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & 0 \\ 0 & b\end{bmatrix}.$$
$a$ is a positive number and $b$ is a negative number. Then applying some transformation $U$ so that one obtains the following matrix.
$$\operatorname{sign}(A) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix},$$
which gives the sign of $a$ and $b$.
Do you think such $U$ exists?

Comment: You have strange notations. $A$ is used as the name of a matrix... which is also the name of one of the entries of the matrix. Also, you should define precisely what $\operatorname{sign}$ means and what are the dimensions of your matrices.

Comment: Have you tried the $1\times 1$ case yet?

Comment: No. The diagonal elements of $UAU^{-1}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and you cannot make them anything other than what they are, see [Diagonalizable matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Comment: @Conifold Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

The remark by Conifold is one reason, but I think the main reason is because $\operatorname{sign}()$ is not linear.

On scalars it is not linear (e.g. $\operatorname{sign}(3-2)=1\neq  \operatorname{sign}(3)+\operatorname{sign}(-2)=0$)

Therefore it is not linear neither on matrices since
$\ \operatorname{sign}_{\text{matrix}}(\alpha I+\beta I)=\operatorname{sign}_\text{scalar}(\alpha+\beta)\,I$

Since $UAU^{-1}$ preserves linearity, it cannot match a non linear one on the RHS.